# Multiple "worko-tabs" On A Single Page

Tags: css

I'm looking at this CodePen:

https://codepen.io/josh_vogt/pen/EaaZbP

```
<div class="worko-tabs">

    <input class="state" type="radio" title="tab-one" name="tabs-state" id="tab-one" checked />
    <input class="state" type="radio" title="tab-two" name="tabs-state" id="tab-two" />
    <input class="state" type="radio" title="tab-three" name="tabs-state" id="tab-three" />
    <input class="state" type="radio" title="tab-four" name="tabs-state" id="tab-four" />

    <div class="tabs flex-tabs">
        <label for="tab-one" id="tab-one-label" class="tab">Tab One</label>
        <label for="tab-two" id="tab-two-label" class="tab">Tab Two</label>
        <label for="tab-three" id="tab-three-label" class="tab">Tab Three</label>
        <label for="tab-four" id="tab-four-label" class="tab">Tab Four</label>


        <div id="tab-one-panel" class="panel active">
          <h3>Responsive CSS Tabs - Flexbox</h3>
          <p>CSS only tabs built using flexbox, when the viewport drops below 600px wide the tabs turn into an accordion by chaging the flex order of the elements.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-two-panel" class="panel">
            Tab two content
        </div>
        <div id="tab-three-panel" class="panel">
            Tab three content
        </div>
        <div id="tab-four-panel" class="panel">
            Tab four content
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

/* Android 2.3 :checked fix */
@keyframes fake {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
body {
  animation: fake 1s infinite;
}

.worko-tabs {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 80%;
}
.worko-tabs .state {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
}
.worko-tabs .flex-tabs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.worko-tabs .flex-tabs .tab {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-height: 40px;
}
.worko-tabs .flex-tabs .panel {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
.worko-tabs .tab {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
}
.worko-tabs .tab:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#tab-one:checked ~ .tabs #tab-one-label,
#tab-two:checked ~ .tabs #tab-two-label,
#tab-three:checked ~ .tabs #tab-three-label,
#tab-four:checked ~ .tabs #tab-four-label {
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  border-left-color: #69be28;
}

#tab-one:checked ~ .tabs #tab-one-panel,
#tab-two:checked ~ .tabs #tab-two-panel,
#tab-three:checked ~ .tabs #tab-three-panel,
#tab-four:checked ~ .tabs #tab-four-panel {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .flex-tabs {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .flex-tabs .tab {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .flex-tabs .tab:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .flex-tabs #tab-one-label {
    order: 1;
  }
  .flex-tabs #tab-two-label {
    order: 3;
  }
  .flex-tabs #tab-three-label {
    order: 5;
  }
  .flex-tabs #tab-four-label {
    order: 7;
  }
  .flex-tabs #tab-one-panel {
    order: 2;
  }
  .flex-tabs #tab-two-panel {
    order: 4;
  }
  .flex-tabs #tab-three-panel {
    order: 6;
  }
  .flex-tabs #tab-four-panel {
    order: 8;
  }

  #tab-one:checked ~ .tabs #tab-one-label,
  #tab-two:checked ~ .tabs #tab-two-label,
  #tab-three:checked ~ .tabs #tab-three-label,
  #tab-four:checked ~ .tabs #tab-four-label {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  #tab-one:checked ~ .tabs #tab-one-panel,
  #tab-two:checked ~ .tabs #tab-two-panel,
  #tab-three:checked ~ .tabs #tab-three-panel,
  #tab-four:checked ~ .tabs #tab-four-panel {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}
```

I want to use the tabs in multiple locations on the same html page. Everything I've tried so far has not worked.

I've got the tabs working fine in a single place on a page, but not on multiple places.

I appreciate any help with this. My brain is not thinking clearly today.

*** Update ***

Here is what I have so far: http://codepen.io/_thomas/pen/MpvEEX

Comment: ids need to be unique -- did you copy/paste and then change the ids in the tab divs and CSS?

Comment: I did in the HTML. For simplicity, I split the above example in two, and used tab-1 & tab-2 in one section, and tab-3 and tab-4 in another.

Comment: You should post your work

Comment: I just updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you moved tabs 3 and 4 out.  You also need to

Fix the radio group at the top

```
<input class="state" type="radio" title="tab-one" name="tabs-state" id="tab-one" checked />
<input class="state" type="radio" title="tab-two" name="tabs-state" id="tab-two" />
<input class="state" type="radio" title="tab-three" name="tabs-state" id="tab-three" />
<input class="state" type="radio" title="tab-four" name="tabs-state" id="tab-four" />
```

Each tab group needs its own name.

AND

Make sure to move the labels out of the section with the tab content.

```
<label for="tab-three" id="tab-three-label" class="tab">Tab Three</label>
<label for="tab-four" id="tab-four-label" class="tab">Tab Four</label>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did: http://codepen.io/_thomas/pen/MpvEEX  ...but only one section works/displays.

Comment: @Thomas you did not give new names to the two <input> tags for the new group.  Change "tabs-state" to "tabs2-state" in just the ones for 3 and 4

Comment: Thanks Lou. I knew it was something simple. My brain is not working today. I have updated my CodePen entry so others can use it.... again many thanks.